# Method not allowed, app running with no errors in heroku logs

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask

I've deployed my flask app on heroku, and i'm getting  "Method not allowed" in my browser at the url.

all my routes have the methods set.  I'm not trying to do much other than access my pages (no forms or anything like that).  I'm using gunicorn.  Just got no idea where I'm going wrong.

here is my main file:

````
from mongo import get_spotify_music
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


music = list(get_spotify_music())


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', title='about')

is_live = os.environ.get("IS_LIVE", None)
url = '0.0.0.0' if is_live else '127.0.0.1'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host=url, port=port, debug=True)```



my Procfile looks like:

```web: gunicorn app:app```

heroku logs --tail looks like:
```2019-07-15T08:25:41.093957+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 325e5224 by user myemail@myemail.com
2019-07-15T08:25:45.035819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2019-07-15T08:25:47.166897+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-15 08:25:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-15T08:25:47.167484+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-15 08:25:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:57502 (4)
2019-07-15T08:25:47.167616+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-15 08:25:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-15T08:25:47.172768+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-15 08:25:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-15T08:25:47.261871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-15 08:25:47 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-07-15T08:25:47.852647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-07-15T08:25:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
````

When I go to the link that's set, i just get a method not allowed, rather than my web page....

Not sure where I'm going wrong here...

Comment: Is there a reason you have 1 endpoint which GETs a HTML body to also support POST? Why not remove it?

Comment: No, to be honest I think GET is a default anyway.  I was just trying to cover all angles, even though the post is pointless...Getting rid of the POST doesn't make a difference

Comment: if you use POST and you try to GET a page, you'll get a 405 error.

Comment: I'm just trying to view the page through the browser, so that would just be a GET.  But POST has been removed from the methods now and I still get the same "Method Not Allowed" response

Comment: have you fully restarted the server? Also, can you update your original code with the updated code?

Comment: Done, and i just restarted my dynos on Heroku and still no joy.  the same Method Not Allowed.  my heroku logs --tail is coming up with the same as last time

Comment: Just seen, in my response headers i'm getting:
Allow: DELETE
Connection: keep-alive

That seem odd?

Comment: Does your Heroku server have the updated code as well? Try a simple `raise Exception()` to see if you got it updated

Comment: All my code on heroku is update with git push heroku master.  raise Exception() gives me nothing in heroku logs --tail

Comment: I've managed to get it up an running,  I have no idea how though.  Not much was changed in this, and it took a few restarts of the dynos.  I think i originally made the heroku with a mispelt procfile (rather than Procfile) and maybe just a load of playing about fixed that.  I appreciate your help!!!